# Alarm Manager,Alarm Dialog and Activity group in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager

I'm trying to implement the **alarm manager** with **alarm dialog** for a activity group.
I can successfully enter into the activity which is scheduled by suspending the alarm dialog from within or outside of my application.
If the activity group is scheduled instead of activity then on suspension of alarm dialog couldn't able to enter into activity group.(Can able to enter into activity group on suspension of the alarm dialog with in a application but not outside of the app.)

**Sample Code is as follows:**

```
public  static  ActivityGroup   group;
```

---

```
public  static  void    switchPendingActivity(Class<?> destClass)
{
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClass(group, destClass);
View view = group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(destClass.getSimpleName(),intent).getDecorView();
group.setContentView(view);
}
```

---

I had starting the activity group by `getLocalActivityManager().startActivity()` and where intent's flag is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` by `setFlags` of Intent.
Even after the above code execution, the activity group didn't came to foreground.
(While debugging the code, I had determine the activity group was didn't came to foreground but some of the internal functions like drawing the tables for the activity of the activity group is executed which is called in onCreate().)

Hence, I'm not sure is there any update is required for above code as to function properly for scheduling the activity in a activity group on suspension of alarm dialog.
Kindly help me to resolve on the above issue.

---

My issue is not suspending the alarm. I want to enter into the activity group through alarm manager scheduler. Activity group should come to foreground after alarm manager scheduling expires but it never happens(but functions in onCreate of the activity of activity group is executed). Above scenario happens only if we come out of our app. Alarm dialog would appear irrespective of within or outside of app. On clicking OK button of alarm dialog that we need to enter into the activity of activity group but it doesn't happen. How to resolve the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AndroidAlarmService extends Activity {



private PendingIntent pendingIntent;





/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startalarm);

    Button buttonCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);



    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



 @Override

 public void onClick(View arg0) {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub



  Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);

  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);



           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

           calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

           calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);



  Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }});



    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



 @Override

 public void onClick(View arg0) {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);



           // Tell the user about what we did.

           Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





 }});



}

}
```

Comment: My issue is not suspending the alarm. I want to enter into the activity group through alarm manager scheduler. Activity group should come to foreground after alarm manager scheduling expires but it never happens(but functions in onCreate of the activity of activity group is executed). Above scenario happens only if we come out of our app. Alarm dialog would appear irrespective of within or outside of app. On clicking OK button of alarm dialog that we need to enter into the activity of activity group but it doesn't happen. How to resolve the above scenario.